# How do I render this data in react?

Tags: json, reactjs

I am new in react. I have tried many different ways to render data but it is not working. I have used map but it is not working or may be I have used it in a wrong way.

I have used CORS enabled browser to do this in ubuntu using this command.

```
google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_tmp"
```

I have used map for this but it is giving error.

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Table from './components/Table.js';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      organizations: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('api call')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        organizations:json,
      });
    },


    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    });
  }

  render() {

    var { isLoaded,organizations } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.organizations);

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>loading....</div>
    }

    else {
     return (
        <div className="App">
          {this.state.organizations.name}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

}

export default App;
```

This  is the data to be rendered:

```
{code: 0, message: "success", organizations: Array(4)}
  code: 0
  message: "success"
  organizations: Array(4)
    0:
       AppList: ["books"]
       account_created_date: "2017-07-04"
       account_created_date_formatted: "04/07/2017"
       can_change_timezone: true
       can_show_document_tab: true
       can_sign_invoice: false
       contact_name: "Siddharth Kothari"
```

Comment: are you getting organizations array logged to console in your render method ?

Comment: yes @FarhanTahir

Comment: data is getting displayed in console.log @FarhanTahir

Comment: ok, the thing  `this.state.organizations` is array and you are accessing it as `{this.state.organizations.name}`. 


If you want to display the name of the first organization then simply do `{this.state.organizations.length ? this.state.organizations[0].name : ''}`

Try this.

Comment: not working @FarhanTahir

Comment: You have stored the whole json to this.state.organizations. To access the name, it would be `this.state.organizations  && this.state.organizations.organizations[0].name` (or contact_name , whatsoever the key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are list-like objects and arrays are zero-indexed the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1. Using an invalid index number returns undefined. Given the following array

```
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];
```

to print the first element, you'll use index `0`.

```js
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];

console.log(arr[0]);
```

To print any element in the array use any valid index.

```js
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];

console.log(arr[1]);
```

You'll get `undefined` if you use invalid index.

```js
const arr = ['this is the first element', 'this is the second element', 'this is the last element'];

console.log(arr[3]);
```

You need to use an index to access the element in your array, and you can also use conditional rendering to display your data and only use one return statement.

```
render() {

  let { isLoaded, organizations } = this.state;
  console.log(typeof organizations);
  organizations = Array.isArray(organizations.organizations) && organizations.organizations || [];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { !isLoaded 
          ? <div>loading....</div>
          : {this.state.organizations[0].contact_name}
      }
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

To render all the items, use [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
render() {

  let { isLoaded, organizations } = this.state;
  console.log(typeof organizations);
  organizations = Array.isArray(organizations.organizations) && organizations.organizations || []; 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { !isLoaded 
          ? <div>loading....</div>
          : <div>
             { organizations.map((organization, i) => <li key={i}>{organization.contact_name}</li>)}
            </div>
      }
    </div>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: organizations.map is not a function...it is giving this error @Junius

Comment: please run the updated code above and tell me what it logs on the console.

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): organizations.map is not a function... and this error @Junius L.

Comment: `organizations` is not an array, you can't use map. please do `console.log(JSON.stringify(organizations, null, 4))`

Comment: replace  `console.log(typeof ..)` with that line.

Comment: no replace the whole line with `console.log(JSON.stringify(organizations, null, 4))`

Comment: It was actually my fault i wrote console.log below Array.isArray......next what to do?

Comment: can you please share the screen shot of the data

Comment: {
    "code": 0,
    "message": "success",
    "organizations": [
        {
            "isOrgNotSupported": false,
            "organization_id": "649283092",
            "name": "ABC",
            "contact_name": "Siddharth Kothari",

Answer (score 0):

Please find below working code with `organizations` array being manually used, you could just replace with `json` instead of `organizations` in `componentDidMount` method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      organizations: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=us,qb&results=1')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      const organizations = [
        {'name': 'something1' , key: 1},
        {'name': 'something2', key: 2 },
        {'name': 'something3', keyL: 3},
      ]
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        organizations:organizations,
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoaded, organizations } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.organizations);

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>loading....</div>
    }
    else {
      return (
         <div>
         {organizations.length && organizations.map(value => {
           return (
             <div key={value.key}>
               {value.name}
              </div>
           )
         })}
         </div>
       );
     }
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Yes it is working but how do i perform it for my set of data?